# Facebook on Android not capturing ACTION_SEND intent images?

Tags: android, facebook

Recently sharing an image to ACTION_SEND has stopped working, but for Facebook only.

Code is something like this:

```
Intent sendIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

// bitmapUri is a cached uri with a content:// prefix, 
// comes from a properly implemented ContentProvider
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);

sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
Intent chooserIntent=Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share this image:");
activity.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Worked fine in the past, and works now in that it will share the image with any Chooser selection (Twitter, GMail, even "Set as Facebook Profile Picture"), but when selecting Facebook from the chooser, image is not there.

I don't think there's problems with the EXTRA_STREAM bitmap because it works on all other targets, even including the Facebook app when choosing "Set as Facebook Profile Picture."

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it was user error on my part.  The content provider had a typo returning the value for getType...not sure why this only affected that particular Facebook target though.